# Want to write a simple SVN update bash script

Tags: bash, ssh, svn

I want to write a simple bash script that will update an SVN working copy in a given directory. The repository is accessed with the `svn+ssh` protocol. The basic process this needs to follow is:

```
#!/bin/bash

# temporarily relax firewall
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 12345 -j ACCEPT

svn up /path/to/working/copy
# prompt for ssh password will be here

# close firewall again
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 12345 -j REJECT
```

What I'm stuck on his how to tell my bash script to supply the password to SSH when prompted. Typing the password on the line after the `svn up` command, predictably, doesn't work.

Is this even possible? If not, alternative ways of achieving this goal will be appreciated.

P.S. I know I should be using SSH public/private key authentication, but the person who runs the server that hosts the SVN repo isn't interested in setting this up for me!

Comment: This might help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/92981/paswordless-rsync-over-ssh-without-key-authentication-un-safe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> P.S. I know I should be using SSH public/private key authentication, but the person who runs the server that hosts the SVN repo isn't interested in setting this up for me!

Well that's very mean! I assume you have SSH access to do this though. Most modern installations of OpenSSH don't require any setup on the server to be done (past installing it). I would seriously consider just attempting to set up a SSH key first:

```
ssh-keygen
ssh-copy-id username@remotehost
```

Then just try `ssh username@remotehost`. If it logs you in, magic, if it doesn't, you've only lost a minute of your life :)

After that you've got options like `expect` and `sshpass` which are much worse because you're hard-coding your password in plaintext. Yuk.

Comment: Well I never expected to be able to set up proper SSH key authentication without root access to the remote server! You've just saved me a big headache -- and the slightly worrying prospect of storing my SSH passwords in plain text -- thanks! :-)

Comment: Glad it worked!

Comment: In adition to that you could try to use sshfs, with this you can mount the SVN to e.g. /home/someuser/svn-repo

This means you just have to type the password once, or even use your shiny key and as long as you leave your machine online, you could work with this folder as it if would live in your home on your machine.